# Can't watch HD-quality videos in VLC Media Player (Ubuntu Mate)

Tags: vlc

The playback is very choppy plus every time I try to rewind the video using the arrow keys on my keyboard, it feels like everything is just slow and there's a noticeable delay between the audio and video tracks. This makes it virtually impossible to watch anything HD. Other files such as MP3s and non-HD-quality videos work just fine.

Before I installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS on my laptop, I used the *Videos* video player that ships natively with Ubuntu as its default video player. The same thing was true even there, HD videos wouldn't play in VLC, but when I opened the same HD files in *Videos*, everything worked fine. I'd really like to use *Videos* again, but the problem is that Ubuntu Mate does not have *Videos* listed as an installable package in its Software Boutique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an Nvidia card? If that's the case, it's a bug, look here: https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/16877

As for installing videos, that's called totem.

```
sudo apt install totem
```

Comment: Thanks. The `sudo lshw -C display` says this about my video card: product: Kabini [Radeon HD 8400 / R3 Series]

Comment: Okay, Maybe it's on bug on radeon as well. But it should work with totem (videos)

Comment: It does, in fact. I just checked.